# All runs are not visible on TensorBoard

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I am using tensorboard to visualize three runs. I have a folder, `logs`, which contains three files:

```
2016-03-18_22-11-12
2016-03-18_22-11-27
2016-03-18_22-23-46
```

when I run `tensorboard --logdir .` (from logs), only `2016-03-18_22-23-46`
 is visible:[image: blu]

And if I delete `2016-03-18_22-23-46` from logs and restart tensorboard, then only `2016-03-18_22-11-27` is visible. Any idea of what's happening here?

Edit: the log files are (to my surprise), quite big: here is the result of `du -h`:

```
1,1G    ./2016-03-18_22-23-46
925M    ./2016-03-18_22-11-12
934M    ./2016-03-18_22-11-27
2,9G    .
```

**EDIT:**
The above run structure can be obtained via logging and checkpointing into [subdirectories of the tensorboard log-dir](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/how_tos/summaries_and_tensorboard/index.html#launching-tensorboard):

```
run_time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S")
FLAGS.train_dir = '/datalab/tf_runs/' + run_time #Directory to put the training data.
summary_writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter(FLAGS.train_dir, sess.graph_def)
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Tensorboard takes a while to parse the log files. If you refresh the graph, you can see it showing more and more iterations. When it finished parsing one, the next run will pop up.

It is a bit annoying that there is no visual indication for this, maybe this is worth a feature request at https://github.com/tensorflow.

Answer (score 5):

Another solution is to use the **--max_reload_threads** option as follows:

```
tensorboard --logdir=runs --max_reload_threads 4
```

The no. of threads could be determined based on the fact that one thread can parse one run at a time.

Answer (score 1):

**TL;DR:** Close any currently running jupyter notebook / python file that has Tensorboard callbacks.

I had the same problem, only one run was visualized in Tensorboard and multiple weren't listed. I waited and refreshed some time, as @etarion pointed out in his answer, but that didn't make the other runs appear.

Then I found out what was happening: I had just finished running training in my notebook file. Then I wanted to open *all* previous runs in Tensorboard, and the only one appearing was the current one I had just trained. I first had to *close the notebook file* and then running Tensorboard showed *all* runs!

For some reason the notebook still being active led Tensorboard only take this run.